# Unable to get Azure AD token in PostMan

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am working on .Net core Azure AD authentication. I have created sample .Net core Application. Below is my code.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });
    }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Below is my config file.

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ClientId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

Below is my Controller code.

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Above code works fine. I am able to hit api and get value. So I am assuming my authentication is working fine. I am trying to hit this API from postman so I am trying to get token in Postman.

[image]

I am getting error Could not complete OAuth 2.0 login. Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [complete sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/) which calling a web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD.

Though you don't have a client application now, you still need to register two applications in Azure portal. One is for client and the other one is for server api.

For your server application, you need to expose an API and add your client application to it.

[image]

Then you can use your client application to request the access token to access server api. The scope should be `api://{server_client_id}/.default`.

Comment: In the above app, I have added Authorize attribute. When i run https://localhost:44351/api/values it returns ["value1","value2"]. So do you need to assume my authentication works fine? Also Is there any way i can test this?

Comment: @Niranjan open an incognito window to check if you can access localhost:44351/api/values without providing authorization.

Comment: I did that. I opened incognito window. It asked me to enter username and password. I  entered my credentials. then my https://localhost:44351/api/values displayed ["value1","value2"]

Comment: So next I want to add some apis and hit to that apis using postman. So for the postman i can get token using as earler we discussed in the other question right?

Comment: @Niranjan I just checked the code, you need to change to use JWT Bearer token authentication instead. Just like juunas pointed.

Comment: Okay thanks. What is Authentication:AppIdUri? I know Client id.

Comment: @Niranjan Click "Expose an API", you can find the Application ID URI. It is the globally unique URI used to identify this web API. It is the prefix for scopes and in access tokens, it is the value of the audience claim. Also referred to as an identifier URI.

Comment: I added Authority as https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompanyname.onmicrosoft.com/ then AppIdUri as api://13469a48-a2ea-45a1-96e7-6580f57b6e3023 now When i run i started getting 401 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199396/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-niranjan).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've defined OpenID Connect + cookies authentication on your app.
You need to change to use JWT Bearer token authentication instead.
I have a sample app here: https://github.com/juunas11/Joonasw.AzureAdApiSample/blob/master/Joonasw.AzureAdApiSample.Api/Startup.cs#L68

Snippet from the sample:

```
            services
                .AddAuthentication(o =>
                {
                    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                {
                    //In a multi-tenant app, make sure the authority is:
                    //o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                    o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                        {
                            Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
                            Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
                        },
                        // In multi-tenant apps you should disable issuer validation:
                        // ValidateIssuer = false,
                        // In case you want to allow only specific tenants,
                        // you can set the ValidIssuers property to a list of valid issuer ids
                        // or specify a delegate for the IssuerValidator property, e.g.
                        // IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, parameters) => {}
                        // the validator should return the issuer string
                        // if it is valid and throw an exception if not
                    };
                });
```

You'll want to set the authority to use v2.0 if your API access tokens are v2 access tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking how my code implementation will effect in getting token? Token is directly coming from azure. In azure when we create app do we need to assign any permission to allow postman to get tokens?

Comment: @Niranjan No there is no need to assign permission to allow postman to get token

Comment: Thanks. I searched in google. Few people said no need to send resource parameter in oauth2.0. If I add resource it will throw error saying resource identifier not required. What are the other possibilities I can check