# Bearer token: The signature is invalid - Default ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api template published to Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, postman

I created a project in VS Community 2019 (latest update) with a template for WebApi .NET Core 2.1 and published it on Azure.
I only added a client secret in the app registration in the portal to use for the call using the authorization code flow.

I was trying to make a GET call using Postman with OAuth 2.0 authorization at the url below:
https://webapi3app.azurewebsites.net/api/values

But I get an unauthorized response with the error header below:
WWW-Authenticate:"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid""

I tried decoding the client secret to BASE64 string but in the repsonse it says that it's an invalid client secret.
I tried changing authorization data to:
- Request URL.
- Request Headers.
I tried several grant types:
- Authorization code.
- Implicit.
- Password Credentials (after changing app to public client).
I tried several scopes:
- Default Microsoft scopes url (https://graph.microsoft.com/.default).
- user.read openid profile offline_access.
- https://aldolekalive.onmicrosoft.com/WebApi3/user_impersonation.
- profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.Read.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
I tried setting client authentication to:
- Send as basic auth header.
- Send client credentials in body.
I tried changing the Authorize attribute to authorize based on only AzureADBearer or only AzureADJwtBearer (because apparently by default they are both enabled with the current configuration) but no luck.
etc.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

I expect to get a response with the body:
"value1, value2"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942665/6049604 - Follow this and see if it helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, your webapi is protected by Azure AD and now you want to call the api. To call the api you need to provide an access token.

To do this, you need to register two applications in Azure AD. One is for client App, the other one is for webapi. You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57917189/10504999).

And here is the [complete sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/). If you don't have an client application now, you can just register an client app in Azure portal, then use this client app to get an access token for your webapi.

> I tried several scopes:

If you are using v2.0 endpoint, the scope should be `api://{server_client_id}/.default`.

Comment: What is the point of using OAuth 2.0 in Postman (to retrieve the access token that I should be able to use to retrieve backend authorized resources) if I create a client app which returns *views* as in the sample you provided. As far as I understood you are suggesting that I use Postman to retrieve resources from the client which retrieves resources from backend (both in azure). Is that correct? It does sound overkill..

Comment: @AldoLeka You have a webapi protected with azure ad, right? And to access the api, you need to provide an access token. If your api is designed to serve as a backend api, a client app is recommended. However, if you just have a webapi, and want others to login in the webapi to use the api.(we can regard it as the webapp) Then only one registration in Azure portal is fine.

Comment: I don't know if this should be a new question but, what I want is basically 1 registration as a web api in azure which has a /token endpoint and other /resource endpoints. In the /token endpoint you pass username and password in the body and get an access token back. Afterwards you can use this token to access /resource endpoints. What I have atm is 1 registration but as I mention in the question I get invalid signature response. What would go into my scope field in Postman request for access token, in case I don't have a client (2nd registration) to expose the api for in azure?

Comment: @AldoLeka  try with {clientId}/.default

Comment: @TonyJu I had to manually configure JwtBearerOptions with audience as ClientId for this to work (AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi does not do this automatically).

Comment: Sorry when T try to add an scope I can not end it with /.default in the  scope name